# Calabash Android - undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: php, android, ruby-on-rails, calabash

I need your help to figure out a solution to an error I'm facing

I'm creating tests for my app with calabash and here is my code :

```
url = 'myUrl'
http = Net::HTTP.new(url, 80)

path = '/login/login.php'

resp, data = http.get(path, nil)   <-- This line fires the error
cookie = resp.response['set-cookie']
```

Here is what I get :

```
undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
./features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:33
```

I don't understand what it refers to ? How can I solve it ? knowing that the line **33** is the one I displayed in the first code snippet.

I think I am calling keys on some undefined variable or empty one but can't figure out which, that's a simple code.

I welcome any idea ! Thank you =)

Comment: Hi Kevin, please could you edit your question to remove or translate the parts in French? StackOverflow is a "English-only" site.

Comment: You're right, I focused too much on what I was saying, thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `nil` argument:

```
resp, data = http.get(path)
```

Comment: I tried and I now get this error :  getaddrinfo: unknown host.  (SocketError)

Comment: Your server name specified in `url` variable is incorrect.

Comment: Okay I'm gonna try and find out today, I'll come back to you later on to confirm your answer ! thx